# COUNT() function containing GROUP BY clause returning error when the count is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm calculating the total user who deposit on today.

I'm counting the total number row of user that deposited on today and group by user.

I will get an error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

When it's 00:00 hrs as it's new day and no user deposit yet.

I need help on how to return 0 if there is no row returned?

I used `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` but it does not work.

I used d_status as an indicator of successful deposit.

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(user_id),0) as total_activeuser
FROM deposit
WHERE d_status = 1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no need for `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_activeuser
FROM deposit
WHERE d_status = 1 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

The problem is that only users with `d_status = 1` are in the result set.  If you want all of them, then one method is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_activeuser
FROM deposit
GROUP BY user_id;
```

If you want the total number of users that match the condition, then perhaps:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from deposit
where d_status = 1;
```